# Can I define Fredholm Index using $\dim \ker ST - \dim \ker TS$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces, operator-theory

$X$, $Y$ are Banach spaces.
Let $S \in L(X, Y)$, $T \in L(Y, X)$, where $L(X, Y)$ denotes the Banach algebra of bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$. If we have that $Id_Y - ST \in \mathbb{K}(Y)$ and that $Id_X - TS \in \mathbb{K}(X)$.
Is it then possible to define Index(T) to be $dim \ker(ST) - dim \ker(TS)$?

The intuition of this definition is that this is true for the case when $X=Y$ is some Hilbert space and $T=S^*$, the adjoint of $S$. I don't know how (if possible) to generalize this to the more general case.

If it is not true in the most general case, can you give a counterexample and a sufficient condition? Thank you!

Comment: Please don't cross post. Better, flag the moderators here, and ask then to migrate this version. Or just go ahead and delete it, and leave only the version on MSE.

Comment: Andres, thanks for your comment. What would you suggest if I am trying to maximize the exposure this question get? I had posted my questions at MSE for 48 hours with no response before I posted it here.

Comment: It is true for some choices of $S$,  for arbitrary Banach spaces $X$, $Y$.  When $X=Y$ are Hilbert spaces it is   false for many  choices of $S$.

Comment: Liviu: Thank you! Would you mind sharing with me one of the many examples where this fail in the Hilbert space? I am still trying to get some intuition about this.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I have deleted my question on MSE to conform to this requirement.

Comment: On the other hand, this kind of question is definitely more appropriate on mathoverflow than on MSE.

Comment: Thank you Delio. I initially thought it would just be a simple exercise that I somehow couldn't figure out so I posted it on MSE lest it be labeled as not "research level", but it seems deeper than I originally thought.